# Lightbox library with Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, lightbox

I'm trying to make an image gallery in Wordpress using this lightbox project http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ I followed the guide to add it but it doesn't work and the console doesn't show any errors.

```
<div class="hvrbox product2iul">
    <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/granite.png" data-lightbox="image01" data-title="Granite>
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/granite.png" alt="Nature">
    </a>
    <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
      <div class="hvrbox-text">Granite</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my functions.php all the other things in there work except for the lighbox

```
<?php
       add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

       function my_scripts_method() {
       wp_enqueue_script(
      'script-name1',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js'
   );
       wp_enqueue_script(
       '  script-name2',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.js'
     );
       wp_enqueue_style(
       'script-name3',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css'
    );
       wp_enqueue_style(
       'script-name4',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick-theme.css'
    );
       wp_enqueue_script(
      'script-name5',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.visible.min.js'
    );
      wp_enqueue_style(
     'script-name6',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css'
    );
      wp_enqueue_script(
     'script-name7',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js'
    );
 }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page to see if your javascript and css you added have been enqueued? Please show us the code you used to include lightbox to wordpress. Did you enqueue the css and js through a template, functions.php , plugin? Did you make sure that jquery is loaded as its dependency? Wordpress requires a few extra steps then plain HTML to get libraries working correctly.

Comment: this is what I added <?php get_header(); ?>
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?> /css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"> and this:   <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: Where was this added?

Comment: at the start of the page-products.php

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d81j4oht/1/ here is the code

Comment: You have a blank space between `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>` and `/css/lightbox.css`. Not sure that's the issue here but you should still fix that.

Comment: Also, please include your CSS & JS files via wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script(). See [Theme Developer Handbook - Including CSS & JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) for more details.

Comment: done, but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Include the following to your functions.php file. Without knowing your exact setup this may need some adjustment. For more specific explanation refer to [Wordpress Developer Handbook - Including CSS & JavaScript.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

**functions.php**

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array('jquery'));

    wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Try adding the jquery dependency on your lightbox.js enqueue. wp_enqueue_script('script-name7', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array('jquery'));

Comment: still when i click the photo the gallery doesn't pop up

Comment: From the sounds of it you are going to have to do some debugging. I would recommend, using firefox or chromes inspect tool to view the pages source code to see if the scripts are even being loaded. verify all your css selectors are correct based on the plugins documentation. Check the console as you click the image to see if any errors are thrown during events, and if all of the above is good. Be sure there are no plugin conflicts by disabling all plugins and testing.

Comment: I also just noticed that you are missing the quotes at the end  of your data-title attribute. currently it is data-title="Granite> and it should be data-title="Granite">

Answer (score 0):

This is my functions.php all the other things in there work except for the lighbox

```
 <?php
       add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

       function my_scripts_method() {
       wp_enqueue_script(
      'script-name1',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js'
   );
       wp_enqueue_script(
       '  script-name2',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.js'
     );
       wp_enqueue_style(
       'script-name3',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css'
    );
       wp_enqueue_style(
       'script-name4',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/slick-theme.css'
    );
       wp_enqueue_script(
      'script-name5',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.visible.min.js'
    );
      wp_enqueue_style(
     'script-name6',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css'
    );
      wp_enqueue_script(
     'script-name7',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js'
    );
 }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

?>
```